# What is the difference between “int *a = new int” and “int *a = new int [5]"?

Tags: c++

I know that “int *a = new int” is used to allocate memory to contain one single element of type int. The “int *a = new int [5]" is used to allocate a block (an array) of elements of type int. But when I run this code

```
int *a=new int;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   a[i]=i;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   cout<<a[i]<<endl;
```

It runs without any error, and shows the correct output, so when should I use "int *a=new int [5]"? Or are they both same in terms of use?
I am using gnu c++ compiler in codeblocks.

Comment: This produces *undefined behavior* and you cannot rely on its results. This is essentially accessing an array out-of-bounds. If you Google you will fine other posts [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Comment: You are accessing memory not allocated to you.  This is undefined behavior, and this type of situation is basically unique to the C++ (and C) language.

Comment: Its similar to doing "int *a;" and then using it.  It will work some of the time until it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want five ints.  Of course you should use

```
int *a=new int[5];
```

Since you are learning C++, it is wise to learn about [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You may expect C++ to stop you or warn you if you are doing something that you shouldn't be doing, such as treating an `int` as if it were an `int[5]`.

C++ isn't designed to track these sorts of mistakes.  If you make them, C++ only promises that it makes no promises what will happen.  Even if the program worked the last time you ran it, it may not work the next time.

Comment: `> If you make them, C++ only promises that it makes no promises what will happen. Even if the program worked the last time you ran it, it may not work the next time.` c++ in a nutshell